I need to send a request from another program to my Odoo environment using an endpoint
This code is creating an endpoint in Odoo that receives parameters in JSON format and uses those parameters to create a new record in the CRM module. The endpoint is designed to accept POST requests and validate if all required fields are provided before attempting to create the new record. But for some reason I received:
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class ApiController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/api/create_crm_lead', type='json', auth='none', methods=['POST'])
    def create_crm_lead(self, **kwargs):
        # Extract JSON data from the request
        data = request.json

        # Validate required fields
        required_fields = ['name', 'contact_name']  # Adjust as per your requirements
        missing_fields = [field for field in required_fields if field not in data]
        if missing_fields:
            return {'error': f'Missing required fields: {", ".join(missing_fields)}'}

        try:
            # Create a new CRM lead
            new_lead = request.env['crm.lead'].sudo().create({
                'name': data.get('name'),
                'contact_name': data.get('contact_name'),
                # Add more fields as needed
            })

            return {'success': True, 'id': new_lead.id}
        except ValidationError as e:
            return {'error': e.name}


You are trying to access the route with a different method. With auth set to none, the request code will not have any facilities to access the current user.
Try the following in code in the browser console:
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8069/api/create_crm_lead", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "Test lead",
        contact_name: "Contact",
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
});

